# Pages for iPhone: how to add a page break?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, pages

I am using Pages on an iPhone (iOS 10.3), and I can't add a page break. Apple's support page (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18098) says to just press the "[image]" key in the format bar above the keyboard, but I don't see it in my iPhone. What I see in my keyboard is just this:

[image]

As you can see, there's no format bar above the keyboard anywhere. Maybe it does show up on an iPad, but as I said, I'm on an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Double-tap where you want the break to occur.
> 2. Tap More button until you see Insert, tap it, then tap Line Break or Page Break.
>
> If you don’t see Page Break, your document is a page layout document and doesn’t use page breaks. In that case, open the document in Pages on your Mac, add a new page, then open the document again on your iOS device.

[Pages for iOS (iPhone, iPod touch): Add line, page, and column breaks](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18098)

[image: Pages - Instructions - Page Break]